# How to jump out of a dead loop automatically in Python?

Tags: python

I have a "do..., until..." structure in Python as follows:

```
while True:
    if foo() == bar():
        break
```

It works fine (jumps out in the end) in most of the cases. However, in some of the cases where the condition is never met, it will get stuck there.

Figuring out what are these cases is kind of difficult, since it is essentially a random process behind. So I wish to set a "timeout" thing for the `while` loop.

Say, if the loop has been running for 1s, but still not yet stops, I wish the loop to terminate itself.

How may I do this?

---

**Update:** Here is the actual code:

```
while True:
    possibleJunctions = junctionReachability[junctions.index(currentJunction)]
    nextJunction = random.choice(filter(lambda (jx, jy): (jx - currentJunction[0]) * (endJunction[0] - currentJunction[0]) > 0 or (jy - currentJunction[1]) * (endJunction[1] - currentJunction[1]) > 0, possibleJunctions) or possibleJunctions)
    if previousJunction != nextJunction: # never go back        
        junctionSequence.append(nextJunction)
        previousJunction = currentJunction
        currentJunction = nextJunction
    if currentJunction == endJunction:
        break
```

Comment: That really depends upon your current scenario. What are `foo` and `bar`? Can you paste your actual code?

Comment: instead of time make it only go a certain amount of iterations

Comment: a) run it in a separate thread, b) remember the start time and check the passed time every iteration (or every N iterations, if they are quick)

Answer (score 7):

```
import time

loop_start = time.time()
while time.time() - loop_start <= 1:
    if foo() == bar():
        break
```

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**

Dan Doe's solution is simplest and best if your code is synchronous (just runs in a single thread) and you know that the `foo` and `bar` functions **always** terminate within some period of time.

If you have asynchronous code (like a GUI), or if the `foo` and `bar` functions you use to test for termination conditions can themselves take too long to complete, then read on.

Run the loop inside a separate thread/process. Run a timer in another process. Once the timer expires, set a flag that would cause the loop to terminate.

Something like this (warning: untested code):

```
import multiprocessing
import time

SECONDS = 10
event = multiprocessing.Event()

def worker():
  """Does stuff until work is complete, or until signaled to terminate by timer."""
  while not event.is_set():
    if foo() == bar():
      break

def timer():
  """Signals the worker to terminate immediately."""
  time.sleep(SECONDS)
  event.set()

def main():
  """Kicks off subprocesses and waits for both of them to terminate."""
  worker_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
  timer_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=timer)
  timer_process.start()
  worker_process.start()
  timer_process.join()
  worker_process.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

If you were worried about the `foo` and `bar` functions taking too long to complete, you could explicitly [terminate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) the worker process from *within* the timer process.

Comment: Hey, what's with the downvote? This is a valid way to handle the problem; and how it's done in asynchronous scenarios (e.g. GUI).

Comment: meh, some people are cranky.

Comment: 'twasn't my downvote, but perhaps you want parens after `main` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a counter. This is a common trick to detect non-convergence.

```
maxiter = 10000

while True:
  if stopCondition(): break

  maxiter = maxiter - 1
  if maxiter <= 0:
    print >>sys.stderr, "Did not converge."
    break
```

this requires the least overhead and usually adapts best to different CPUs: even on a faster CPU, you want the same termination behavior; instead of a time-based timeout.

However, it would be even better if you would detect being stuck e.g. with some criterion function that no longer improves.